# Consecutive IF statements in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on some code in Node.js. Basically I am trying to analyze and apply logic on the query part of the URL. The abstract of my situation is below:

```
If(condition1){run1};
If(condition2){run2};
else{run3};
```

When F-F (condition1-condition2) run3 happens
When T-F run3 happens (run1 should've happened...)
When F-T run2 happens 
When T-T run1 and run2 happen

I tried:

```
If(condition1){run1};
else{run4};
If(condition2){run2};
else{run3};
```

Where run4 is blank.

What is going on here? I want run1 to happen if condition1 is met, run to happen if condition2 is met and both if both are met and none if none are met.

TIA

Comment: @jahroy I have just updated my answer after going through the question again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (condition1) {
    run1;
}
if (condition2) {
    run2;
}
if (! condition1 && ! condition2) {
    run3;
}
```

Comment: so the presence of an else{} in the same bracket alters the behavior of preceding if{}'s within the same bracket?

Comment: No... Your logic is just incorrect.  Try stepping through your code.  You'll see why you're not getting what you want.  In the example you provided, if `condition1` is true and `condition2` is false, `run1` and `run3` will both execute.

Comment: No to what exactly? and a run1 and run3 in that scenario is what I want but does not happen. With your format it does work. Im interested to know why it works.

Comment: @nemo - No: the presence of an _else_ in the same bracket does not alter the behavior of preceeding _ifs_.  Your code did not work because your _if/else_ statements were structured wrong.  If you step through your code when `condition1` is true and `condition2` is false, you'll see why your original code was incorrect.  It will execute `run1` and `run3` which is **not** the behavior you described.

Answer (score -2):

Below is the correct solution with proper brackets

```
If(condition1){run1};
If(condition2){run2};
If(!condition2 && !condition2){run3};
```

Comment: that is not helpful. please re-read my question. if condition1 and condition2 are met only run1 will execute in your solution